# Why does automatic boxing work in eclipse but not in javac?

Tags: java, eclipse

This code:

```
Integer ints[] = new Integer[]{'1', '2', '3'};
```

compiles just fine in eclipse, but javac (both version 1.6.0_27 and 1.7.0) gives the following error:

```
BoxTest.java:4: incompatible types
found   : char
required: java.lang.Integer
               Integer ints[] = new Integer[]{'1', '2', '3'};

BoxTest.java:4: incompatible types
```

Why?

I assume it's some kind of compiler flag, but digging trough eclipse to figure it out is not exactly straight forward.

Comment: Wow. That really does compile in Eclipse.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Converting char (to int) to Integer poses a problem? Especially when it's in an initializer?

Comment: `Integer i = '1';` compiles in Eclipse. Does it compile with `javac`?

Comment: Check your JDK compliance level at Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler. It may not be 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: @MattBall Multiple widening conversions/boxings in one assignment are allowed. A `char` may convert to an `int` and that can be auto-boxed to an `Integer`. That's why it works. Agreed with PaoloVictor that this is probably a mismatch between the JDK used in the Eclipse environment and javac.

Comment: @G_H that would explain it - I definitely thought that the JLS only allows a single widening conversion or boxing.

Comment: My JDK compliance level _is_ set to 1.6, and I'm using the standard 1.6 JRE.

Comment: @G_H do you have any links to some docs that say multiple boxings can occur?

Comment: @Steve is it multiple boxing? I assumed char -> int is implicit, and int -> Integer is the only boxing required.

Comment: Huh, I thought there was something explicitly about this in the JLS, but now I can't find it. Multiple boxings are inherently impossible, I guess, but a chain of a conversion followed by a boxing should be possible.

Comment: `Integer i = '1';` does not compile with standard `javac`. Neither with 1.6 nor with 1.7. It fails with the error message `incompatible types found: char required: java.lang.Integer`. I wonder why anyone would try to assign a character literal to a numeric variable in the first place.

Comment: @Nico char to int is implicit but Character to Integer is not. This works: Integer ints[] = new Integer[]{(int)'1', (int)'2', (int)'3'};

Comment: @a_horse right, but `Integer i = (int)'1';` does. Seems kind of unecessary to require explicit casting in an initializer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right! It only works with an explicit cast to int first. Doesn't work in NetBeans either. If it compiles in Eclipse, I wonder if this has something to do with the default incremental compiler there.

Comment: FWIW Eclipse may give a warning: `The expression of type char is boxed into Integer`. (Switch on "Potential Programming Problems"/ "Boxing and unboxing conversions" in the compiler options). Note that that is a _different_ message than the one from javac.

Comment: @SteveClaridge right, so the answer seems to be that the eclipse compiler allows boxing after implicit conversion while javac doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that @MattBall already said that... :P

Comment: Just tried the "wrong" form in Eclipse and it really works! I'm speechless...

Comment: JDT compiler (i.e. eclipse) has some bugs and doesn't follow strictly the JLS. My favorite nonsense is testing double for (not) NaN and it does show warning (i.e. if (d==d) //). Some of the generics were/are broken, etc. File it as bug and move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `javac` is not doing, is not autoboxing, but is an automatic cast. In `javac` it compiles with:

```
Integer ints[] = new Integer[] { (int) '1', (int) '2', (int) '3' };
```

The same happens with just one `Integer`, again in `javac`, I've to do the explicit cast to compile:

```
Integer a = (int) '1';
```

But here is what I found. Using [Eclipse JDT batch compiler](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm) from the command line it works, even without the casts:

```
$ java -jar org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.1.v_B76_R37x.jar -classpath rt.jar \
  -1.6 Appo.java
```

I've looked at the [options of `javac`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and I don't think there is any way to change this behaviour.

I've to infer that the difference is caused by the fact that **Eclipse is not using `javac` internally, but the JDT compiler**.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Eclipse uses the (nee) Sun JDT libraries, not the Sun javac compiler.

Answer (score 4):

As already noted by *stivlo* the Eclipse JDT compiler silently treats the code like this:

```
Integer refI = Integer.valueOf((int)'a');
```

But the *Java Language Specification* says in [chapter 5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2) (emphasis mine):

> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is
>   assigned (§15.26) to a variable: the type of the expression must be
>   converted to the type of the variable. Assignment contexts allow the
>   use of **one** of the following:
>
> ```
> * an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> * a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> * a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> * a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> * an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.
> ```

The `(int) 'a'` cast is the first conversion, the `Integer.valueOf(int)` is the second conversion. The `javac` compiler enforces the rules by allowing only one conversion.

So it seems, you have found a bug in the Eclipse JDT compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I found a lot of confusion on this thread on how Eclipse compiles Java code. Here's the deal - 
Eclipse uses its "own" JDT compiler, which has *nothing to do* with either Sun or Sun's(now Oracle's) javac compiler. It is an independently developed compiler, licensed under EPL, and follows the JLS, just as javac does. So whatever does/does not compile with javac, does/does not compile with Eclipse JDT.

That said, the problem reported here looks like a bug in the Eclipse compiler.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362279

Comment: Yup, thanks Nico. I just wanted to clarify the compiler behaviour as well so that people dont have to play guessing games anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preference -> Compiler -> Errors/Warning -> Potential programming problems
-> Boxing and unboxing conversions; set the value to Error

Comment: No that's different. That setting in eclipse makes automatic boxing an error, but automatic boxing is allowed by javac.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the -source flag set to a pre auto boxing version of Java? for example

javac -source 1.4 BoxTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Eclipse IDE makes use of Java @SuppressWarnings:

http://knol.google.com/k/suppresswarnings-annotation-in-java#

The moral equivalent from javac are the XList:xxx options:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options

ADDENDUM:

1. Eclipse uses the standard JDK, of which javac is a part.
2. Part of the difference can be accounted for by Eclipse's internal use of (what other languages sometimes call "pragmas"), such as @sSuppressWarnings.
3. The MAIN difference, however, is that Eclipse uses the JDT libraries, which sit UNDER the javac executable.
4. Here's an excellent discussion:

   - [JDT More correct than Javac](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=136204)

'Hope that helps .. PSM